# closed subspace in a TVS

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$X$ is a TVS and $Y$ is a proper subspace of $X$, can we conclude that $Y$ is closed?

my attempt: if $Y$ is open, then there exist a neighborhood $V\subset Y$ of $0$ since $0\in Y$, we have:
$$X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z^+}nV$$
from Rudin's *functional analysis* theorem 1.15.

so $\forall x\in X, \exists n$ such that $n^{-1}x\in V\subset Y$, at last we get $x\in Y$ since $Y$ is a subspace. contradiction.

---

But I'm confused why we always emphasis the proposition "the subspace of a **finite**-dimensional TVS is closed"? Rudin has a long proof of this proposition in theorem 1.21, and I don't know why we need finite? Is there any counterexample in the infinite case?

Comment: Your argument only shows that $Y$ is not open. "Closed" is not the same as "not open."

Comment: @JackLee thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if your TVS is induced by a norm and complete then a subspace is closed iff it is complete. For example $\mathscr l^2(\mathbb N)$ is complete with the standard norm but the subspace given by finite linear combinations of $\{e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not complete and thus not closed.

($\sum_{n=0}^N 2^{-n} e_n$ is for example a Cauchy sequence, whose limit cannot be expressed as a finite linear combination of the $e_n$.)

On the other hand normed finite dimensional (real or complex) vector spaces are always complete. So, since any subspace of a finite dimensional vector space is also finite dimensional, any subspace of a normed finite dimensional vector space is automatically closed.